# Executing client-side script on link click

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need my web page to open a window and enable a disabled button when a link or a button is clicked.
From what I've read on other posts on here, if I try and open a new window in Page_load most browsers will assume it's a pop-up and block it so I've been trying to do it client side with JS.

Currently, I'm trying it with a link declared like so:

`Please click <a href="javascript:OpenDoc()">here</a> to open the document.`

This calls the following JS:

```
    function OpenDoc() 
    {
        <%= btnSubmit.ClientID %>.Visible = true; 
        Window.Open('GetDocument.aspx') 
    }
```

Unfortunately, instead of rending the JS as "btnSubmit.Visible = true" it comes out as "MainContent_btnSubmit.Visible = true" which doesn't work.

Assuming this is the best way of doing what I want, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change visibility property through javascript but you can use the following code instead of it :

```
var control = document.getElementById('<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>');           
control.disabled = true;
```

In this case the button will be disabled and if you need to hide button not disableing it then use the following code :

```
var control = document.getElementById('<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>');           
control.style.display= "none";
```

Hope this is helpfull based on my understanding to your problem

Comment: I'd not even thought about the visibilty but using document.getElementByID worked for me (as did using control.disabled). Thanks for your help!